# Issue when launching on Eclipse application

Tags: java, android, launch

I'm trying to develop my own application for Android devices. 
I'm working with API Level 13 AVD. I succeed in installing the application on the device, but when I try to lauch it, I'm getting those errors :

```
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.smart.framework.SmartApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.smart.framework.SmartApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.ijoomer.src-2.apk]
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:482)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3684)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:122)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1062)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:132)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4123)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.smart.framework.SmartApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/com.ijoomer.src-2.apk]
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:251)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:540)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:500)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:941)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:477)
04-13 20:34:44.720: E/AndroidRuntime(566):  ... 11 more
```

Thanks for trying to solve, I'm quite disappointed by this :(

Comment: Be sure that the activity is mentioned in the manifest.

Comment: @eightx2 - have you even read the logcat output? It didn't mention any activities missing from the manifest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to clean your project and reinstall the application.

*Project->Clean...*

If it doesn't help change your virtual **device version** and **RAM size**(set to 512MB). If you aren't using virtual device, disconnect your physical device and restart Eclipse, then reconnect your device.

Comment: I tried with oters virtuel device version, it didn't change anything unfortunately :/

Comment: Have you unchecked **Launch from snapshot** when running the existing virtual device?

Comment: I have on the AVD Snapshot checked, but I don't remember where I can fin "Launch from snapshot"... Where is it ? :)

Comment: **Android Virtual Device Manager->[check virtual device]->Start...->Launch from snapshot**. Uncheck it and try.

Comment: I found, I unchecked, and it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Do the old android projects install and run on your device without any problem?

Comment: Yes! I could install the .apk on my real smartphone without any problems. I had some problems with my computer, and lost all my project... So I got back the .apk from my smartphone and decompiled my application, I thought it would run, but now not... I was finishing the project, and I don't want to restart all from the beginning... That's why I'm trying to solve this application...

Comment: Are all the `.java` and `.xml` files in place?

Comment: Yes I think all are... Well, I think I will have to look around java and xml file, if they are correct... ^^

Comment: If no solution is found, I suggest you to create a new project and copy all `.java` and `.xml`(layout, values) files there. Have you cleaned the project?

Comment: Yes I cleaned all.
I will do that I think, maybe the best solution ;)
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure I will in a few days ;)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have some library that you use, but it is not part of the APK (`com.smart.framework.SmartApplication`). Include that in APK at it should run. (Your app throws `ClassNotFoundException`)